# sql structure of client/supplier satisfaction survey

Tags: sql

I need to build a form to send to several clients. Each client will answer 5 questions, relative to their current suppliers. They will be able to select the suppliers they are working with from a dropdown list and, for each supplier, the client will answer each question ticking a radio button number from 1 to 5 depending on the quality of the service they receive from the supplier. The question are the identical for every supplier.

How to build the Sql table structure for this?

I thought about building two tables, clients and suppliers. The client table has a client per row, which has one column with the name of the client and the other with (an array?) the suppliers they have.

The suppliers table, instead, would be a supplier per row with its name and the 5 questions and the relative answers as columns. The Client table would have the foreign key in the suppliers column, that would communicate with the suppliers table.

The problem is, every client has different entries for the questions column of the suppliers so I don't know how to differentiate the single supplier for each client who will fill the form.

How would your approach be on this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple ERD of how I would do that:

[image: ERD of client/supplier survey DB]

### Explanation

The tables you already have:

- The **Client** table stores data directly about client.
- The **Suppliers** table stores data directly about the supplier.

Then I've added:

- A dedicated **Questions** table allows you to decouple the questions from the DB schema. You can add/remove questions at will in the future as rows in this table.

Lastly, instead of adding more columns, relationships are given their own tables. Don't be afraid of having more tables.

- The **ClientSuppliers** table records the links between a Client and a Supplier. This will help determine who to send survey questions to about which supplier.
- The **ClientSuppliersAnswers** table records the response of a specific client to a specific question about a specific question (note the 3 FKs).

Comment: This is great  and I definitely understand much more the general approach now :). One more question though: In the form, the client answers would only populate the ClientSuppliersAnswers table?

Comment: Yes, the idea is that anything new is just a record in a table.

Comment: Is there not a little redundancy in this ERD? You do not need to link ClientSuppliersAnswers to Client and Suppliers individually since you build a table that agregate them. You just need to link ClientSuppliersAnswers to ClientSuppliers I think.

Why decoralate ClientSuppliers association from ClientSuppliersAnswer? But maybe I am thinking wrong :P

Comment: You are right. One could make a ClientSupplierID primary key in the ClientSuppliers table, and use ClientSupplierID as a foreign key in the ClientSuppliersAnswers table instead of ClientID and SupplierID.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain a little.

But first, if you want to design correctly a data structure you have to learn quite few things :

- Normal forms : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/database-normalization-normal-forms/
- MERISE or UML : (I have preferences for MERISE that is by experience most adapted to the database world, but it is quite difficult to have resources in english on it)

  - UML : http://tdan.com/uml-as-a-data-modeling-notation-part-1/8457
  - Merise :  http://y.mieg.free.fr/EFREI-DBMS/07-Design-E-R.pdf

(And this is only for RDBMS, if you need NoSQL structure : you will need to roll-up your sleeves a little more)

As a piece of advice I will give a methodology that I hope quite clear in data modelisation :

- First : define all your terms with the structure that follows

| name 
| type [alpha; alphanumerical; numerical; boolean; datetime; entity] 
| a proper description
| which entity is depending on

- Second : define all your relations and cardinalities
  For exemple : 1 client = n suppliers / 0 suppliers = n client
- Third : Design your relational model
  (* Fourth : Anticipate performances you will need for your warranty period at minimum)
- Fifth : Choose the technology which receive your structure by raise your humidified finger to the sky if you skipped the fourth part.
- Sixth : Design your physical model (what is going to be put on your hardware)

**Now, what you are here for**

On a postgresql rdbms, this is a possible solution:

```
create table supplier (id int primary key, suppliers_name varchar(50));
create table client (id int primary key, client_name varchar (50) unique);
create table question (id int primary key, question_definition varchar(500));
create table question_client (id int primary key, id_suppliers int references supplier(id), id_client int references client (id), id_question int references question(id), question_date timestamp, answer varchar (500));
```

**Now : why ?**

With the amount of information you gave me I figured that you needed, why not, only one table after all.
QUESTIONS (client_name varchar, supplier_name varchar, answer_to_question_1 varchar, answer_to_question_2 varchar [...])

And keep the question in your middleware instead of your database.

This form is wrong in many ways and I am sure you figure already some of them, but I have seen this so much time, I felt like explain why is it so wrong.

- **Lesson 1 : no doubled data** Keep that in mind : **doubled data are a nightmare**. And a living one when you need to have a match on only one client client 'Smith' but someone registered it as 'Smiss'... Who knows if it is the same? The guy that had registered the client? Sorry : in not in the company anymore. The client? Yeah : tell to your client that he paid you for a job that you cannot perform. You will be received. (there is few exceptions, but I can't tell everything in one post).

So from this lesson, we define the structure has follows :

- QUESTION (question_description varchar)
- CLIENT (name varchar)
- SUPPLIER (name varchar)

But how to link all of that?

- **Lesson 2 : primary keys**. A lot of modelisation will tell to you that you need to use a field that is unique as a primary key. Or a combination of them. For example : you could be tempted to use the CLIENT name as a primary key. Okay. And in the future you will have another client with the same name... Why not? Can you predict the future? Do you think your healthcare number is unique? Okay : are you sure it will be in the future? Everything changes, everyday. My advice : **use a one column int primary key, always**
- **Lesson 3 : apply the normal forms** : There is plenty of example why on the web and my post is already a little to long to explain all of them. But trust me and just do it. You'll learn why studying them.

What have we now ?

- CLIENT (id int PK, name varchar)
- SUPPLIER (id int PK, name varchar)
- QUESTION (id int PK, question_definition varchar)

Now we can link all of those with the following table :
QUESTION_CLIENT (id int PK, id_client int REF, id_question int REF, id_supplier int REF, answer varchar)

At this I had a datetime attribute to let you the latitude to answer more than one time the question to your client and find when you did.

There is a lot more to say about relationnal databases modelisation but I hope this is a good start for you to answer : 'How would your approach be on this?' by yourself in the future.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Thanks for all the links and the explanation :). This is undoutably a nice answer. Although the working solution above we first in chronological order and it works as well. Thanks so much anyway, I am still a complete beginner in everything concerning MERISE and UML.

Comment: Don't worry : we all started at the beginner level :) Give a look to the comment that I put at the answer firstly posted. I don't think it is entirely correct ;) Have a nice continuation in the glorious world of RDBMSs !

Comment: Thanks so much for the effort you took to answer to a stranger like me :). Really really appreciated