# Database design - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I'm looking to build\fill my DB with data etc. problem is I'm not sure how to map out the fields.

This is what i have:

- Name - This is a string
- Operator Name - This is a string
- Description - This is a string
- Dates - This field is a range of dates that depend on the type and also impact the prices. 
  This is how it looks:

  ```
  01/08/2019 - 22/08/2019
  05/09/2019 - 26/09/2019
  03/10/2019 - 24/10/2019
  ```
- Types - This field is also a range that has multiple choices that impact the price i.e. 1 person or 2 person etc.
- Prices - This field represents different prices that are impacted by type and also related to the dates.

I'm not sure how to design a DB for fields having multiple options that are related, any suggestions?

Comment: What is the primary (unique) key of that table? The name? Do you have multiple ranges for a single name (assuming that is the primary key) or can a single name have multiple ranges? The same question for the "Types" and "Prices". If there are multiple ranges, types and prices how do _they_ relate to each other? Does the "first" range belong to the "first" type and the "first" price? Without more details it sounds as if you are looking for a one-to-many relationship

Comment: The primary key is either the ID that's added to each row or it could be the name i guess since it the most reoccurring field.
i have multiple ranges for a single name as per my post both the price and date has multiple values for the same name.
Regarding types prices and date they are all aligned per their order so yes the first of each is aligned with the others

Answer (score 0):

As a_horse_with_no_name commented it : there is not enough information to answer you THE answer that is going to fulfill your needs.

But, as I understand your post, maybe this modelisation is a start.
[image: model_1]

What does it mean :
A product can have multiple types for a period of time. But not twice the same on the excact same period of time.
This setting of product and type is made by an operator.
This setting of product and type is submitted to a price.

It is possible to put the idOperator as NOT NULL. 
It is possible to put the Price as NOT NULL.

But still : this is an interpretation of what you have write, not the firm truth.

Comment: I would love to share more details, just let me know whats missing
The product is a bundle\package and the other fields correspond to that meaning that dates are ranges of possible dates the bundle is for, type is a range of bundle types and price is a range of prices so if one chooses Date 1.1.10 - 2.2.10 and type A he gets price A, type B gets price B accordingly while the date ranges are no affecting anything apart from the duration of the bundle.
the operator is the seller of sorts.

Is it more clear now?

Comment: Not a lot more clear in fact. 

What is linking an operator and a product? A link in database modelisation is between two entities (the most of the time though). For example :
a product can be used by many operators
an operator can only use one product.

In this regards : could you tell what is linking Type, Product and Operator?

Second advice : make a data dictionary. (name of the data, type of the data, description of the data, in which entity the data is, under which constraint).

Comment: The operator is just another field that is part of the Product so it only adds more info on the product just like the name and description.
a product can only have 1 operator and the operator is only operating 1 job per product.

Regarding the dictionary i have that kinda as part of my code so it looks like this:
Name: String
Operator: String
Summary: String
Dates: List
Types:List
Prices:List
They are all part of the same product and their connection between them is the order, for the lists that is so as i mentioned each element is aligned with the same index for the other lists.

Comment: Also as a side note, since i'm new to stackoverflow is there a way to make the comments seem more readable? this isn't looking the same way as i type it.

Comment: For the comment style : I do not know either :P If you find it I am interested as well.

Comment: Concerning the database modelisation, another advice : do not conceive it with a code first point of view. Modelize it from a text that is explaining to you the functions of your system and the basic needs. It will lower your error ratio on your modelisation.

MERISE is still a good modelisation method. UML too (but a little less than MERISE. But that is only my point of view.)

Comment: As a reflexion I can re route you on an answer that I already put in form for this type of question (not the accepted answer nonetheless) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55866338/sql-structure-of-client-supplier-satisfaction-survey/55867735#55867735